# Is it safe to put bash commands in git commit messages?

Tags: bash, git

Is it safe to have arbitrary bash commands in a git commit message like

```
git commit -m "rm -rf mydir"
```

I'm concerned that there might be somewhere this commit message could be executed unintentionally

Comment: it's when you store that command in an `.sh` file, and then there is a virus eating the file so that only the `rm -rf mydir` remains

Comment: There is nothing in a normal git workflow that would try to execute the contents of your commit messages.

Comment: Feel free to add the commands there. Probably not the best thing to do on the one-line summary of a change _but_ nothing that impedes you technically from doing it if so you want.